# How to make that google wont follow some of the wordpress pages?

Tags: e-commerce

How to make that google wont follow these two pages:

http://mysite.com/products-page/your-account/
http://mysite.com/products-page/checkout/

Thanks!

P.S. Im using worpdress with WP Ecommerce plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Create a sitemap.xml excluding the pages you just mentioned.
2. Create a robots.txt which disallows the Google robot from looking at certain files:

   To exclude all robots from parts of a server:

> User-agent: *
>   Disallow: /product-page/checkout

This is not WordPress specific.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the wp seo plugin by yoast http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ and select no index no follow on the pages you want to block. Also dont worry google cannot see the users account details in products-page/your-account/ it will just see a empty page.

[image: wp seo plugin]